# When passing a path as flowfile attribute XMLValidator doesn't work, but when passing the exact same path in the schema directly it does

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

i'm fairly new with working with NiFi. We're trying to validate an xmlfile, except we need to use a different xsd depending on some value passed in the file. Extracting and routing on the name wasn't an issue, and we stored the desired filepath in an attribute (xsdFile).

However, when trying to use that attribute in the XMLValidation processor, it changes the path and gives an error. When I copy the path from the attributes and copy it to the schema, it works, so the path itself isn't wrong.

Attribute passed in flowfile:

```
xsdFile:  
C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\NiFi\FLOW_RESOURCES\input\validatexml\camt.053.001.02_CvW_2.xsd
```

XMLValidation processor properties:

```
Schema File: ${xsdFile}
```

Error:

```
Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Schema file not found at specified location: C:\Users\MYNAME\DOCUME~1\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Schema file not found at specified location: C:\Users\MYNAME\DOCUME~1\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Schema file not found at specified location: C:\Users\MYNAME\DOCUME~1\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0
```

Why does this not work? Is there another way to do this, or do we need to route to different XMLValidators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation for this processor:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateXml/index.html

Schema File:

> The path to the Schema file that is to be used for validation
>   Supports Expression Language: true 
>   **(will be evaluated using variable registry only)**

So, flow file attribute can't be used for this parameter